# question if this job should be a red flag or not

Tags: manual-testing, unit-tests

I have only talked to the recruiter so far and he seems legit, but recruiters always try to make a job sound fluffy. I literally only applied because im going to be on unemployment and I know I have to apply once a week at least. However, I am in the process of moving out and it would be nice to have a job but well..I dont NEED the money right now, I have a lot saved up. I was teaching myself java right now and was planning on applying for java interns or qa automation jobs. I feel I shouldnt throw myself into a job because I meet the requirements, but the one big thing I can see gaining from this job is the experience. If i am the only qa guy, ill learn so much, but I am also concerned on who will teach me if I am the only qa guy..Please offer any advice on the companies or situation

Comment: "I am unemployed right now and this job would pay the same amount" Pay the same amount as what?

Comment: Hi @Jacob-Hong - I'm closing this question as it's really not on topic for the site, for a number of reasons. http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/241/are-questions-about-the-legitimacy-specific-qa-job-postings-appropriate/ I appreciate your worries about trying to figure out if a role will be good for you or not, can I suggest you try posting your question in chat to get feedback? That's a more suitable location for discussion. Otherwise, you might find http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ is worth trying for this one?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to be a qa lead really, I planned on moving into
>   development within the next 5 years.

If you don't want to be a QA Lead, then don't take a job which explicitly states that it will become a QA Lead.

If you want to be a Developer, look for Developer jobs.

This might help: http://www.allthingsquality.com/2012/05/if-you-dont-really-want-career-in.html